# Why is the condition performed when it shouldn't be?

Tags: python, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a sequence of characters that I want to insert into a 2D table. But, despite the if condition : when I reach a character '*', it goes into the if condition, whereas it should go directly into the else.

```
if str(tab_2D[q + 5][1]) != '*':
     print("IN")
     if table_transition[int(etat1) + 1][ord(symbole) - ord('a') + 2] == " ":
         table_transition[int(etat1) + 1][ord(symbole) - ord('a') + 2] = etat2
     else:
         table_transition[int(etat1) + 1][ord(symbole) - ord('a') + 2] += ',' + etat2
else:  # si le symbole EST epsilon
     if table_transition[int(etat1) + 1][int(symbol) + 2] == " ":
          table_transition[int(etat1) + 1][int(symbol) + 2] = etat2
     else:
          table_transition[int(etat1) + 1][int(symbol) + 2] += ',' + etat2
q += 1
```

Here's the proof that ' * ' does go into the `if` condition because `"IN"` **is** displayed once when it's really a ' * ' character that is being compared. It should not be displayed.

Here's proof:

[image: screenshot of some text]

Do you know why?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but a) your indentation under the first `if` you posted looks off, and b) `' ' != '*'` so that _should_ trigger that if, no?

Comment: I reach the ' * ' character so logically ' * ' == ' * ' so != is no longer true. So it should go into the else, right?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, I had forgotten to add q += 1 before the main else